# How to get jQuery selector result in the @Ajax.ActionLink routevalues object?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following @Ajax.ActionLink code:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Assign Ownership",
                 "AssignOwnership",
                 new
                 {
                   techLogCode = Model.TechLog.Code,
                   salesRepId = "",
                 },
                 new AjaxOptions
                 {
                   HttpMethod = "POST",
                   Confirm = "Are you sure you want to take ownership?",
                   OnSuccess = "reloadWindow",
                   OnFailure = "displayAjaxError"
                 })
```

I have a dropdown list with an id of owner and I want to use the selected value as the salesRepId.  How do I get that value in my @Ajax call?

This is the jQuery I think will work.

```
$("#owner option:selected").val()
```

Comment: Have you tried `salesRepId = "$('#owner option:selected').val()
"?`

Comment: The jquery never runs.  It literally passes the $('#owner option:selected').val() as salesRepId.

Comment: Can you please post how that ajax action link looks like on client side?

Comment: Your ajax action link is rendered as a link something like `<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-confirm="Are you sure you want to take ownership?" data-ajax-failure="displayAjaxError" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="reloadWindow" href="/Home/AssignOwnership?techLogCode=Value1&salesRepId=value2">Assign  Ownership</a>` what you can do is use jQuery/javascript  to modify href to include selected value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your action link on a div and use jQuery to modify a link for your ajax on client side.

```
    <div id="ajaxForm">    
          @Ajax.ActionLink("Assign Ownership",
             "AssignOwnership",
             new
             {
               techLogCode = Model.TechLog.Code,
               salesRepId = "",
             },
             new AjaxOptions
             {
               HttpMethod = "POST",
               Confirm = "Are you sure you want to take ownership?",
               OnSuccess = "reloadWindow",
               OnFailure = "displayAjaxError"
             })
   </div>


   <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ajaxForm a").click(function (event) {
            $(this).attr('href', "/YourControllerName/AssignOwnership?techLogCode='Value1'&salesRepId= value2");
     });
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help this worked for me.  Still learning ajax and jquery.  I've got a ways to go yet.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the dropdown in an AjaxForm and change your `ActionLink` to a submit button? Include the `techLogCode` field as a hidden field